# harmonica notes/tuning

Tags: harmonica

Of the many 10-hole harmonicas I have, only one enables me to play almost all of the true notes in a song: The one I refer to is a Hohner which I have misplaced, having owned it for 40 years: It has different notes to a 'blues' type. Does anybody know what type of tuning I am referring to and if any manufacture(s) offer something similar in a 10-hole version?
Thanks Trevor

Comment: Are you sure it was a ten hole? And do you mean with out overblowing?

Comment: Probably a chromatic https://www.hohner.de/en/instruments/harmonicas/chromatic/chrometta/chrometta-10

Comment: @b3ko - a chromatic ought to be capable of providing *all* the notes of a song, not *'almost all of the true notes*', surely?

Comment: What song - what key -  and which notes are impossible to play?

Comment: @tim I’m just guessing because there isn’t a heck of a lot of info here. That’s why it’s a comment and not an answer.